# Python BeautifulSoup doesn't exist

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Trying to figure out how to keep my script running if a value isn't found.

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
html = "my.html"
get_data = open(html,'r').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(get_data, "lxml")
title = soup.find_all("tr", {"class":"clock-seg on-clock paid"})[-1]
```

Then I do stuff with the "title" variable once the data is found. If that specific item isn't found in the HTML fileS, I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fclm.py", line 40, in <module>
    title = soup.find_all("tr", {"class":"clock-seg on-clock paid"})[-1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

The code snippet above is  in a loop so it's going through multiple HTML files. If I have an empty one, I just want it to keep going and not return an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `try-except` block

**Ex:**

```
html = "my.html"
get_data = open(html,'r').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(get_data, "lxml")
try:
    title = soup.find_all("tr", {"class":"clock-seg on-clock paid"})[-1]
except IndexError:
    pass
```